# Calling Function from another selenium file

Tags: selenium

I am trying to call a function from another file in selenium python. But when the call is sent from one to other file, instead of accessing only that certain function, the whole script will start running, until finished. Then the control will comeback to original file.

Comment: Your code trials?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can we see how you're importing the function or module from another file?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.